# What is the difference between optimization algorithms and Ensembling methods?

Tags: optimization, methods, data-science, difference

I was going through ensemblling methods and was wondering what is the difference between the optimization techniques like gradient descent etc. And ensembling techniques like bagging, boosting etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimization like Gradient Decent is a single model approach.   Ensemble per Wikipedia is multiple models.  Constituents in the ensemble are weighted for overall consideration. Boosting (per Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning seems to say that it is retraining with a focus on missed (errors) in a model.

To me this is like single image recognition in a monocular fashion vs. binocular image recognition.  The two images being an ensemble.  Further scrutiny requiring extra attention to errors in classification is boosting.  That is to say retraining on some errors. Perhaps error condition data were represented too infrequently enough to make good classifications (thinking black swan here).  In vehicles, this could be like combining infrared, thermal, radar and lidar sensor results for an overall classification.  The link above has really good explanations of each of your areas of concern.